# Syncronization of global variable for java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am writing performance test on java.
The main idea create method loadTest(String url, int threadNumber, int requestNumber) that will return total time for success requqest and number of success request.
But I am stuck with returning data.

So now if I run this test 
MyRunnable.getTotalTime() and MyRunnable.getCountSuccessRequest() return 0; (first string in console)
and correct value in the end of output in console. 
I want that they return

How I could return correct value?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TestMain {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println("Start test.");
    TestMain test = new TestMain();
    test.loadTest("http://www.google.com/search?q=java", 10, 50); // will execute 50 get request in 10 threads.
}

public void loadTest(String site, int threadNumber, int requestNumber) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNumber);
    for ( int i = 0; i < requestNumber; i++ ) {
        Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(site);
        executor.execute(worker); 
    }
//System.out.println("Total time " + MyRunnable.getTotalTime() + " total success request = " + MyRunnable.getCountSuccessRequest() );//still not work
}
}
```

Class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Chrome";
    private  static int count = 1;
    private  static int countSuccessRequest = 0;
    private static long totalTime ;
    private final String url;
    public MyRunnable(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    //<________edit__________>
    SyncronizedCounter sc = new SyncronizedCounter();
    //<________edit__________>

    public static long getTotalTime() {
        return totalTime;
    }
    public static int getCountSuccessRequest() {
        return countSuccessRequest;
    }

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con =  (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT); 
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        long elapseTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        totalTime += elapseTime;
        count++;
        if (responseCode == 200 ) {
            countSuccessRequest ++;
        }
        //<________edit__________>
        sc.incrementTime(elapseTime);
        //<________edit__________>
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url );
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        System.out.println("Response time : " + elapseTime + " milliseconds\n");
        System.out.println("----Total time for all request = " + totalTime + " mileseconds");
        System.out.println("----Total count of request =  " + count);
        System.out.println("----Count of success request =  " + countSuccessRequest);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
 //<________edit__________>
 public class SyncronizedCounter{
    private  long totalTime1 = 0;

    public synchronized void incrementTime( long time){
        totalTime1 += time;
    }

    public synchronized long getTime() {
        return totalTime1;
    }
}
//<________edit__________>
}
```

My additional edit mark as <**______edit________**>. I have add wraper class and instance in method run(). How I can get the last value in TestMain.class

Answer (score 0):

Create a capsule object `Stats` (it must be non-primitive) and give it methods

```
public synchronized void addTotalTime(long elapsed)
public synchronized void addSuccessCount(long elapsed)
public synchronized void addTotalCount(long elapsed)
```

This ensures that no `+=` operations are performed concurrently so no race condition will put uncertainty into what value will be stored into the variable.
See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) for technical detail.

---

A code stub would look like this

```
private class Stats {
    private int success, total;
    private long time;

    public synchronized void addTotalTime(long elapsed) { time += elapsed; }
    public synchronized void addSuccesCount(int c) { sucess += c; }
    public synchronized void addTotalCount(int c) { total += c; }

    public long getTotalTime() { return time; }
    public int getSuccessCount() { return success; }
    public int getTotalCount() { return total; }
}
Stats s = new Stats();
// in worker:
s.add...(...)
// at end:
System.out.println(s.get...());
```

Comment: This is the main question for me. How it should work?

Comment: Where are you stuck? How to create a class? How to write those methods? How to access those methods?

Comment: This is the main question for me. How it should work? Create new class SyncronizedCounter{ private long totalTimeMy = 0; public syncronized void incrementTime(long time){ totalTimeMy += time;} public syncronized void getTime(){ return totalTimeMy;}}.               Than I should create instantce in MyRunnable and change it in method run. but how I get last value. I don't know how to do this in TestMain.class.

Comment: @user3737721 Just add getters for the values as well. See my edit for a working class and sample calls.

Comment: @user3737721 by calling your favorivte method of output? To obtain the value you just need to keep the `Stats` object static across your program, or keep it in `MainClass` and give a `Stats` instance to your custom `Runnable` during initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `executor.submit(yourRunnable)` and your threads return the time they were working as `Future<Integer>`. Afterwards just sum up all returned Futures.

Comment: but, I want to get time only for success request. Not for all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a running count and not just the totals at the end I would use [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) to handle the updates and use Callables and Futures instead of Runnable to handle the http requests.

In general it is best to avoid explicit synchronization and to rely on java.util.concurrent when possible.

Below are examples solutions in both Java 6/7 and Java 8.

**Java 6/7**

```
public class TestMainJdk7 {

    public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {

        final TestRun testRun = new TestRun("http://www.google.com/search?q=java", "Chrome", 5, 5, 100000L);

        final TestResults testResults = testRun.execute();

        // Uncomment and add Apache commons-math to report quantiles, mean, min, max, standard deviation
        // for (int quantile = 5; quantile <= 100; quantile += 5) {
        // System.out.println(quantile + ": " + testResults.rawDescriptiveStatistics.getPercentile(quantile));
        // }
        // System.out.println("mean: " + testResults.rawDescriptiveStatistics.getMean());
        // System.out.println("min: " + testResults.rawDescriptiveStatistics.getMin());
        // System.out.println("max: " + testResults.rawDescriptiveStatistics.getMax());
        // System.out.println("standard deviation: " + testResults.rawDescriptiveStatistics.getStandardDeviation());

    }

    public static class TestResults {

        private final double[] rawDurations;

        public final TestRun testRun;

        public final List<TimedHttpRequestResult> timedHttpRequestResults;

        // Uncomment and add Apache commons-math to report quantiles, mean, min, max, standard deviation
        // public final org.apache.commons.math.stat.descriptive.DescriptiveStatistics rawDescriptiveStatistics;

        public TestResults(final TestRun testRun, final List<TimedHttpRequestResult> timedHttpRequestResults) {

            this.testRun = testRun;

            this.timedHttpRequestResults = timedHttpRequestResults;

            final List<Long> successfulDurations = new ArrayList<Long>();

            for (final TimedHttpRequestResult timedHttpRequestResult : timedHttpRequestResults) {

                if (timedHttpRequestResult.isSuccess()) {
                    successfulDurations.add(timedHttpRequestResult.duration);
                }
            }

            this.rawDurations = new double[successfulDurations.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < successfulDurations.size(); i++) {
                this.rawDurations[i] = successfulDurations.get(i);
            }

            // Uncomment and add Apache commons-math to report quantiles, mean, min, max, standard deviation
            // this.rawDescriptiveStatistics = new org.apache.commons.math.stat.descriptive.DescriptiveStatistics(
            // this.rawDurations);
        }

    }

    public static class TestRun {
        public final String urlString;
        public final String userAgentString;
        public final int threadNumber;
        public final int requestNumber;
        public final long timeoutInMillis;

        private long totalDurationSoFar;
        private int totalRunSoFar;
        private int totalSuccessfulSoFar;

        private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        public TestRun(final String urlString, final String userAgentString, final int threadNumber,
                final int requestNumber, final long timeoutInMillis) {
            this.urlString = urlString;
            this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
            this.requestNumber = requestNumber;
            this.userAgentString = userAgentString;
            this.timeoutInMillis = timeoutInMillis;
        }

        public TestRunStatus updateCounts(final long duration, final int responseCode) {
            this.lock.lock();
            try {
                this.totalDurationSoFar = this.totalDurationSoFar + duration;

                this.totalRunSoFar++;

                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    this.totalSuccessfulSoFar++;

                }
                return this.currentStatus();
            } finally {
                this.lock.unlock();
            }

        }

        public TestRunStatus currentStatus() {
            return new TestRunStatus(this.totalDurationSoFar, this.totalRunSoFar, this.totalSuccessfulSoFar);
        }

        public TestResults execute() throws InterruptedException {

            final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.threadNumber);

            final Map<TimedHttpRequest, Future<TimedHttpRequestResult>> timedHttpRequestFuturesByRequest = new HashMap<TimedHttpRequest, Future<TimedHttpRequestResult>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < this.requestNumber; i++) {

                final TimedHttpRequest timedHttpRequest = new TimedHttpRequest(this);

                timedHttpRequestFuturesByRequest.put(timedHttpRequest, executor.submit(timedHttpRequest));
            }

            final List<TimedHttpRequestResult> timedHttpRequestResults = new ArrayList<TimedHttpRequestResult>();

            for (final Map.Entry<TimedHttpRequest, Future<TimedHttpRequestResult>> timedHttpRequestFuture : timedHttpRequestFuturesByRequest.entrySet()) {
                final TimedHttpRequest timedHttpRequest = timedHttpRequestFuture.getKey();
                try {

                    timedHttpRequestResults.add(timedHttpRequestFuture.getValue()
                        .get(this.timeoutInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    timedHttpRequestResults.add(new TimedHttpRequestResult(timedHttpRequest, e,
                            this.updateCounts(0, -1)));
                }
            }

            executor.shutdown();

            return new TestResults(this, timedHttpRequestResults);

        }

    }

    public static class TestRunStatus {
        public final long totalDurationSoFar;

        public final int totalRunSoFar;

        public final int totalSuccessfulSoFar;

        TestRunStatus(final long totalDurationSoFar, final int totalRunSoFar, final int totalSuccessfulSoFar) {
            this.totalDurationSoFar = totalDurationSoFar;
            this.totalRunSoFar = totalRunSoFar;
            this.totalSuccessfulSoFar = totalSuccessfulSoFar;
        }
    }

    public static class TimedHttpRequestResult {

        //@formatter:off
        public static final String TO_STRING_FORMAT = "\nSending 'GET' request to URL : %s"
                + "\nResponse Code : %s"
                + "\nResponse time:  %s"
                + "\n---- Total time for all request = %s milliseconds"
                + "\n---- Total count of request =  %s"
                + "\n---- Count of success request =  %s";
        //@formatter:on

        public final TimedHttpRequest timedHttpRequest;

        public final long duration;

        public final int responseCode;

        public final Exception exception;

        public final TestRunStatus testRunStatus;

        public TimedHttpRequestResult(final TimedHttpRequest timedHttpRequest, final long duration,
                final int responseCode, final TestRunStatus testRunStatus) {
            this.timedHttpRequest = timedHttpRequest;
            this.duration = duration;
            this.responseCode = responseCode;
            this.testRunStatus = testRunStatus;
            this.exception = null;
        }

        public TimedHttpRequestResult(final TimedHttpRequest timedHttpRequest, final Exception exception,
                final TestRunStatus testRunStatus) {
            this.timedHttpRequest = timedHttpRequest;
            this.duration = -1L;
            this.responseCode = -1;
            this.testRunStatus = testRunStatus;
            this.exception = exception;
        }

        boolean isSuccess() {
            return this.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format(TO_STRING_FORMAT, this.timedHttpRequest.testRun.urlString, this.responseCode,
                    this.duration, this.testRunStatus.totalDurationSoFar, this.testRunStatus.totalRunSoFar,
                    this.testRunStatus.totalSuccessfulSoFar);
        }
    }

    public static class TimedHttpRequest implements Callable<TimedHttpRequestResult> {

        public final TestRun testRun;

        public TimedHttpRequest(final TestRun testRun) {
            this.testRun = testRun;
        }

        @Override
        public TimedHttpRequestResult call() throws Exception {
            final URL url = new URL(this.testRun.urlString);

            final HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", this.testRun.userAgentString);

            final long startTime = System.nanoTime();

            final int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            final long endTime = System.nanoTime();

            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            final long duration = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(endTime - startTime);

            final TimedHttpRequestResult timedHttpRequestResult = new TimedHttpRequestResult(this, duration,
                    responseCode, this.testRun.updateCounts(duration, responseCode));

            System.out.println(timedHttpRequestResult);

            return timedHttpRequestResult;
        }

    }
}
```

**Java 8**

```
public class TestMainJdk8 {

    public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {

        final TestRun testRun = new TestMainJdk8.TestRun("http://www.google.com/search?q=java", "Chrome", 5, 5,
                100000L);

        final TestResults testResults = testRun.execute();

        // Uncomment and add Apache commons-math to report quantiles, mean, min, max, standard deviation
        // for (int quantile = 5; quantile <= 100; quantile += 5) {
        // System.out.println(quantile + ": " + testResults.rawDescriptiveStatistics.getPercentile(quantile));
        // }
        // System.out.println("mean: " + testResults.rawDescriptiveStatistics.getMean());
        // System.out.println("min: " + testResults.rawDescriptiveStatistics.getMin());
        // System.out.println("max: " + testResults.rawDescriptiveStatistics.getMax());
        // System.out.println("standard deviation: " + testResults.rawDescriptiveStatistics.getStandardDeviation());

    }

    public static class TestResults {

        private final double[] rawDurations;

        public final TestRun testRun;

        public final List<TimedHttpRequestResult> timedHttpRequestResults;

        // Uncomment to report quantiles, mean, min, max, standard deviation
        // public final org.apache.commons.math.stat.descriptive.DescriptiveStatistics rawDescriptiveStatistics;

        public TestResults(final TestRun testRun, final List<TimedHttpRequestResult> timedHttpRequestResults) {

            this.testRun = testRun;

            this.timedHttpRequestResults = timedHttpRequestResults;

            this.rawDurations = timedHttpRequestResults.stream()
                    .filter(TimedHttpRequestResult::isSuccess)
                    .mapToDouble(timedHttpRequestResult -> timedHttpRequestResult.duration)
                    .toArray();

            // Uncomment and add Apache commons-math to report quantiles, mean, min, max, standard deviation
            // this.rawDescriptiveStatistics = new org.apache.commons.math.stat.descriptive.DescriptiveStatistics(
            // this.rawDurations);
        }

    }

    public static class TestRun {

        public final String urlString;

        public final String userAgentString;

        public final int threadNumber;

        public final int requestNumber;

        public final long timeoutInMillis;

        private long totalDurationSoFar;

        private int totalRunSoFar;

        private int totalSuccessfulSoFar;

        private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        public TestRun(final String urlString, final String userAgentString, final int threadNumber,
                final int requestNumber, final long timeoutInMillis) {
            this.urlString = urlString;
            this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
            this.requestNumber = requestNumber;
            this.userAgentString = userAgentString;
            this.timeoutInMillis = timeoutInMillis;
        }

        public TestRunStatus updateCounts(final long duration, final int responseCode) {
            this.lock.lock();
            try {
                this.totalDurationSoFar = this.totalDurationSoFar + duration;

                this.totalRunSoFar++;

                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    this.totalSuccessfulSoFar++;

                }
                return this.currentStatus();
            } finally {
                this.lock.unlock();
            }

        }

        public TestRunStatus currentStatus() {
            return new TestRunStatus(this.totalDurationSoFar, this.totalRunSoFar, this.totalSuccessfulSoFar);
        }

        public TestResults execute() throws InterruptedException {

            final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.threadNumber);

            final Map<TimedHttpRequest, Future<TimedHttpRequestResult>> timedHttpRequestFuturesByRequest = IntStream.range(
                    1, this.requestNumber)
                    .mapToObj(index -> new TimedHttpRequest(this))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), timedHttpRequest -> executor.submit(timedHttpRequest)));

            final List<TimedHttpRequestResult> timedHttpRequestResults = timedHttpRequestFuturesByRequest.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(entry -> {

                        final TimedHttpRequest timedHttpRequest = entry.getKey();

                        try {

                            return entry.getValue()
                                    .get(this.timeoutInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                        } catch (final Exception e) {
                            return new TimedHttpRequestResult(timedHttpRequest, e, this.updateCounts(0, -1));
                        }
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            executor.shutdown();

            return new TestResults(this, timedHttpRequestResults);

        }
    }

    public static class TestRunStatus {

        public final long totalDurationSoFar;

        public final int totalRunSoFar;

        public final int totalSuccessfulSoFar;

        TestRunStatus(final long totalDurationSoFar, final int totalRunSoFar, final int totalSuccessfulSoFar) {
            this.totalDurationSoFar = totalDurationSoFar;
            this.totalRunSoFar = totalRunSoFar;
            this.totalSuccessfulSoFar = totalSuccessfulSoFar;
        }
    }

    public static class TimedHttpRequestResult {

        //@formatter:off
        public static final String TO_STRING_FORMAT = "\nSending 'GET' request to URL : %s"
                + "\nResponse Code : %s"
                + "\nResponse time:  %s"
                + "\n---- Total time for all request = %s milliseconds"
                + "\n---- Total count of request =  %s"
                + "\n---- Count of success request =  %s";
        //@formatter:on

        public final TimedHttpRequest timedHttpRequest;

        public final long duration;

        public final int responseCode;

        public final Exception exception;

        public final TestRunStatus testRunStatus;

        public TimedHttpRequestResult(final TimedHttpRequest timedHttpRequest, final long duration,
                final int responseCode, final TestRunStatus testRunStatus) {
            this.timedHttpRequest = timedHttpRequest;
            this.duration = duration;
            this.responseCode = responseCode;
            this.testRunStatus = testRunStatus;
            this.exception = null;
        }

        public TimedHttpRequestResult(final TimedHttpRequest timedHttpRequest, final Exception exception,
                final TestRunStatus testRunStatus) {
            this.timedHttpRequest = timedHttpRequest;
            this.duration = -1L;
            this.responseCode = -1;
            this.testRunStatus = testRunStatus;
            this.exception = exception;
        }

        boolean isSuccess() {
            return this.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format(TO_STRING_FORMAT, this.timedHttpRequest.testRun.urlString, this.responseCode,
                    this.duration, this.testRunStatus.totalDurationSoFar, this.testRunStatus.totalRunSoFar,
                    this.testRunStatus.totalSuccessfulSoFar);
        }
    }

    public static class TimedHttpRequest implements Callable<TimedHttpRequestResult> {

        public final TestRun testRun;

        public TimedHttpRequest(final TestRun testRun) {
            this.testRun = testRun;
        }

        @Override
        public TimedHttpRequestResult call() throws Exception {
            final URL url = new URL(this.testRun.urlString);

            final HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", this.testRun.userAgentString);

            final long startTime = System.nanoTime();

            final int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            final long endTime = System.nanoTime();

            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            final long duration = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(endTime - startTime);

            final TimedHttpRequestResult timedHttpRequestResult = new TimedHttpRequestResult(this, duration,
                    responseCode, this.testRun.updateCounts(duration, responseCode));

            System.out.println(timedHttpRequestResult);

            return timedHttpRequestResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need only total in the end.) I will check your code thanks.

Comment: If that's the case use AtomicInteger.increment for the request count and success count and AtomicLong.getAndAdd(duration) for the total duration.

Comment: The RentrantLock is needed to allow the values to all be changed in a single transaction.